# is there any way to add a discount coupon to a hotel booking?

Tags: sabre

We're trying to offer coupon discounts to customers who book hotels through our agent. Is there some way to pass on a message to the hotel to split the bill between the agent and the customer?

I tried adding a text object to the guarantee message, like this:

```
<ns1:Guarantee Type="G">
  <ns1:CC_Info>
    <ns1:PaymentCard Code="VI" ExpireDate="2018-01" Number="4444333322221111"/>
    <ns1:PersonName>
      <ns1:Surname>Somebody</ns1:Surname>
    </ns1:PersonName>
  </ns1:CC_Info>
  <ns1:Text>PLEASE CHARGE 8.30AUD TO AGENT AND 157.7AUD TO CUSTOMER</ns1:Text>
</ns1:Guarantee>
```

But Sabre just merged it into one string, invalidating the credit card details:

```
 <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    <stl:HostCommand LNIATA="222222">0H1¥4/GVI4444333322221111EXP 01 18-SOMEBODYPLEASE CHARGE 8.30AUD TO AGENT AND 157.7AUD TO CUSTOMER/SI-TIDS - 9XXXXXX1. INFO - JUST TESTING, DISREGARD</stl:HostCommand>
    <stl:Message code="0">‡MAXIMUM GUARANTEE LENGTH 69 CHARACTERS‡</stl:Message>
    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
  </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
```

Does anyone know how to do this properly - or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an agreement with the hotel chain or property beforehand, there is no formal mechanism to accomplish what you are trying to do. Sending a message to the hotel may be possible, but enforcing the way they charge is not part of the Sabre workflow. You'd be better off trying to negotiate a corporate rate with the properties you are looking to book that included a discount and/or modified commission structure for your TMC.